# How to pass number as a string to a rosservice?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, yaml, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rosservice that takes a string as an argument. That string may be an integer (or rather, the string representation of an integer). However, when I try to call the service with the number, it tries to pass it as a number, which fails. I've tried putting the number in quotes, but that doesn't change anything. I think it has to do with the rosservice command line utility using yaml to parse the command.

Is there any good solution or workaround?

```
$ rosservice call /config_set gnss 1
ERROR: Unable to send request. One of the fields has an incorrect type:
  field configuration must be of type str

srv file:
string device
string configuration
---
bool successful
bool reboot_required
string message
```

The srv file, if needed:

```
# Set a configuration setting

string device # The device whose configuration is being set, either a name or a number
string configuration # The new configuration option for the device, either a name or a number
---
bool successful
bool reboot_required
string message # Either an error message or more specific response. May be from rosflight_io or from the firmware
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341196/how-to-pass-number-as-a-string-to-a-rosservice?/) by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2020-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [documentation for `rosservice`](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine#Command-line_and_Strings) -- specifically the section on "Command-line and Strings". That would suggest something like:

```
rosservice call /config_set 'gnss' '!!str 1'
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3